Terminals types, pseudo and regular
I wouls like to know the difference between TTYs and PTYs I cannot see any difference as a complete beginner. Could anyone help?

TTY = Tele-TYpe, and was once ONLY a machine. Example They were literally the first "terminal".  PTY = PseudoTeletYpe which allows emulating a TTY.  In a nutshell, PTY's are "terminal emulators".
